# Unable to parse JSON string

Tags: jquery, json, cordova

this is my JSON response from server :-

```
{
    "Details": [
        {
            "ID": 234872,
            "Name": "asdfg",
            "Address": "hasgdkjfgsjaf,asfuysdfg",
            "Email": "",
            "Mobile": "",
            "Profile": "gwekjrg ",
            "Amt": 0,
            "Date": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

this is my js code that i have written to parse it and use it in my app :-

```
function getDetail(madeUrl) {
        $.ajax({
        url: madeUrl,
        type : "GET",
        dataType : "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(msg) {
                $("#detail tr").remove();
                var searchResponse = msg.Details;
                var html;
                $.each(searchResponse, function(index, data) {
                    html = '<tr><td>' + data.Name + '</td> <td>' + data.Amt + '</td></tr>' + data.Profile + '</td></tr>' + data.Date + '</td></tr>';
                    $("#detail").append(html);
                });
                $('#report').fadeIn();
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert("errorstatus: " + xhr.status + " ajaxoptions: " + ajaxOptions + " throwError: " + thrownError);
            },
            complete : function() {

            }
        });
}
```

but it throws an error like unable to parse JSON string.Unable to find out the reason.Any help ?

Comment: It is a phonegap application not a native one

Comment: Are you sure the server returns the original `JSON` data

Comment: yes i have checked its validity...and it is valid JSON

Comment: add the line msg=jQuery.parseJSON(msg).

Comment: @UjjawalKr, Please check the latest answer...Hope it should helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code. It's working fine for me. Hope it should helpful for you. Please let me know. Thanks.

**Html:**

```
<div id="detail"></div>
```

**Script:**

```
var j ='{"Details": [{"ID": "234872","Name": "asdfg","Address": "hasgdkjfgsjaf,asfuysdfg","Email": "","Mobile": "","Profile": "gwekjrg ","Date": ""}]}';

var json = $.parseJSON(j).Details;
$(json).each(function(i,val){
    $.each(val,function(k,v){
    console.log(k+" : "+ v); 
    $("#detail").append(k+" : "+ v + " <br />");
});
});
```

Demo URL:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Jebasuthan/3dtKt/1/)

Comment: he receives json from a server and the json should be automatically evaluated by the jquery.get function, so no need for parseJSON here.

Comment: @QuickFix, You are correct instead of parsing, in success method you have json result. So you just call the json result to the json variable. It will work..

Comment: @UjjawalKr, Please let me know source is not working or Demo link is not working...? Paste these code in your Success function,
$(searchResponse).each(function(i,val){
    $.each(val,function(k,v){
    $("#detail").append(k+" : "+ v + " <br />");
});
});

Comment: @Jeba Demo is working fine but when i tried this code in my app it didn't worked, however i am trying your recent code sample..will let you know ...Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you have unparsable JSON message, it means that somehow your JSON is not seen as valid by JQuery.

To be sure, I would remove dataType and contentType from the ajax call (default datatype is "Intelligent Guess" which means jquery will automatically parse JSon if it detects it or send text otherwise) and add the following line at the begining of the success function :

```
alert(msg === Object(msg)?"json received:\n"+JSON.stringify(msg):"text received:\n"+msg);
```

Comment: it returns the complete html file in alert not the responded data

Comment: when i removed the dataType from the code it throws a different error like : TypeError: Result of expression 'e' [undefined] is not an object

Comment: strange that you receive html code instead of the json, is the json displayed correctly in the response when you use the same url in a browser?

Comment: yes its shows correctly. I have also checked the json i got is valid or not from http://jsonlint.com its showing valid json